# In how many ways can we arrange $6$ red, $3$ blue and $4$ green balls in a row such that there is no adjacent green balls?

Tags: combinatorics

All ball of one color are **identical**.

My idea is to calculate first the total numbers to arrange the $13$ balls. It equals $\dfrac{13!}{6! 3! 4!}=60060.$

Then I want  remove the cases where all $4$ green ball are adjacent, then remove cases where $3$ green ball are adjacent and the cases  $2$ green ball are adjacent.

For the  first case (all $4$ green ball are adjacent) I have got $\dfrac{9!}{6! 3!}=84 $ cases,  but cant  calculate rest cases. Any   help please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are $9$ non-green balls; line them all up in a row.  Now consider the $8$ spaces between the balls, and the $2$ spaces at the ends—$10$ in all.  We can put the $4$ green balls in any of those spaces (with no more than one in each space).  Thus the number of such arrangements is

$$
\binom{10}{4} = 210
$$

To this must be considered the multiple ways in which the $3$ blue balls can be placed amongst the $9$ non-green balls.  This is

$$
\binom{9}{3} = 84
$$

Thus the total number of possible arrangements is

$$
84 \cdot 210 = 17640
$$

Comment: Shouldn't you multiply by the ways to arrange the non-green balls?

Comment: Yup.  I'll fix that.  Total brain fade.

Comment: @Leox: The expression  $\binom{9}{3}\binom{10}{4}$. is correct.

Comment: André Nicolas Yes,I see now. @Brian Tung  Thank you!